# Textarea autosize problem with firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have problem with textarea autosize. It's working very well in IE but in firefox, chrome and other web browsers it gives me only 3 text rows and if these rows are full i need to start scroll. Can someone help me?

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<style type="text/css">
*.a120 { color : black; font-family : Calibri , sans-serif; 
font-size : 18.00pt; font-style : normal; font-weight : 700; 
padding-left : 1px; padding-right : 1px; padding-top : 1px; 
text-align : center; vertical-align : top }
*.a121 { background : #BFBFBF; border-left : 1.00pt solid windowtext; 
border-right : 1.00pt solid black; border-top : 1.00pt solid windowtext; 
color : black; font-family : Calibri , sans-serif; font-size : 13.00pt; 
font-style : normal; font-weight : 700; padding-left : 1px; 
padding-right : 1px; padding-top : 1px; text-align : center; 
vertical-align : top; height : auto; overflow : visible }
*.a122 { border-bottom :0.75pt solid windowtext; 
border-left : 1.00pt solid windowtext; border-top :0.75pt solid windowtext; 
color : black; font-family : Calibri , sans-serif; font-size : 11.00pt; 
font-style : normal; font-weight : 400; padding-left : 1px; 
padding-right : 1px; padding-top : 1px; text-align : left; 
vertical-align : top; height : auto; overflow : visible }
*.a123 { color : black; font-family : Calibri , sans-serif; 
font-size : 11.00pt; font-style : normal; font-weight : 400; 
text-align : left; vertical-align : top; height : auto; overflow : visible }
*.a124 { border-bottom :0.75pt solid windowtext; 
border-right : 1.00pt solid black; border-top :0.75pt solid windowtext; 
color : black; font-family : Calibri , sans-serif; font-size : 11.00pt; 
font-style : normal; font-weight : 400; padding-left : 0px; 
padding-right : 1px; padding-top : 0px; text-align : left; 
vertical-align : top; height : auto; overflow : visible }
table {width: 668;table-layout: fixed } 
</style>
</head>

<body>

<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='668' style='border-collapse:collapse' align='center'>

<tr style="height:1px;">
<td width='23'></td>
<td width='23'></td>
<td width='23'></td>
<td width='23'></td>
<td width='23'></td>
<td width='23'></td>
<td width='23'></td>
<td width='23'></td>
<td width='22'></td>
<td width='22'></td>
<td width='22'></td>
<td width='22'></td>
<td width='22'></td>
<td width='22'></td>
<td width='22'></td>
<td width='22'></td>
<td width='22'></td>
<td width='22'></td>
<td width='22'></td>
<td width='22'></td>
<td width='22'></td>
<td width='22'></td>
<td width='22'></td>
<td width='22'></td>
<td width='22'></td>
<td width='22'></td>
<td width='22'></td>
<td width='22'></td>
<td width='22'></td>
<td width='22'></td>
</tr>

<tr style='height:24pt'>
<td class='a120' sheetid='1' rowid='1' colid='1' colspan='30'>
Personal data
</td>
</tr>

<tr style='height:17pt'>
<td class='a121' sheetid='1' rowid='2' colid='1' colspan='30'>
1. Main data


</td>
</tr>
<tr style='height:auto'>
<td class='a122' sheetid='1' rowid='3' colid='1' colspan='3'>
1.1 Name:
</td>

<td class='a124' sheetid='1' rowid='3' colid='4' colspan='27'>
<textarea class='a123' tabindex='1' style=' width:100%; padding-right:1px'></textarea>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your issue - especially as this seemingly has nothing to do with javascript, but CSS instead. The size of a textareas initial size is dependent on the browser. It can easily be set as needed by amending your CSS. For example adding `height: 100px` to your `*.a123` class will make the textarea much taller. I'd also suggest you have a look at CSS best practices as there is a lot of code duplication going on there.

Comment: Also, look to specify a DOCTYPE otherwise you'll not have consistency in browsers.

Comment: have you tried <textarea class='a123' tabindex='1' style=' width:100%; **min-height:400px** ; padding-right:1px'></textarea> Ooops! min-height instead of height or both

Answer (score 0):

Use min-height:

```
textarea {width:100%;height:400px;min-height:400px; padding-right:1px}
```

or add to your *.123 class:

```
*.123 {width:100%;height:400px;min-height:400px; padding-right:1px
```

remove the inline style